# jQuery connected sortable append new container via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following sortable structure:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="sortable">
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 22</li>
    <li>Item 33</li>
    <li>Item 44</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and javascript

```
  $(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".sortable"
    }).disableSelection();

    $("button").click(function() {
      $("<ul class=\"sortable\"> </ul>").appendTo("#wrap");
    });
  });
```

but when I add new list using on click event, it does not become sortable, and does not accept any items.

I have also created jsbin: https://jsbin.com/xirehenubi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

The console of your JSBin example complains that `$.sortable` is not a function indicating that JQueryUI was not correctly initialized.

The reason is that you are including `jquery-1.11.3.js` then JQueryUI, then `jquery-2.1.4.js`. Just remove the last script and your example works.

EDIT:

When you create a new list you must also configure this list, e.g.:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var newList = $("<ul class=\"sortable ui-sortable\"> </ul>");
    newList.sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortable"
    }).disableSelection();
    $("<br>").appendTo("#wrap");
    newList.appendTo("#wrap");
});
```

Comment: I have updated jsbin, but that still does not solve the problem You can not drag items to a new list container